# Why did Bradford give Chen a ring?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-rookie

In the last scene of **The Rookie S02E12**, Officer Bradford gives a white ring to Officer Chen. Why does he do this? Has the ring come up before??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Officer Bradford was looking for Lucy when she was buried, he noticed her ring sparkling in the sun and that’s what led to him finding her burial site. That’s the same ring that he gave her back.

Comment: If I remember correctly, she threw away the ring deliberately, to leave a trace ...